# wondershaper is not throttling my bandwidth

Tags: linux, bandwidth

I'm on a dedicated server (proxmox-ve-2.6.32: 3.4-165 (running kernel: 2.6.32-42-pve)) with a 95th percentile rule and want do be sure to not break it. I have a 1gbit link and my contract offer me a 95th percentile on 100mbits. So I would like to limit my bandwith always to 100 mbits.

I've tried to use wondershaper without any sucess and need some help:

```
#ifconfig
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr xxx
      inet6 addr: xxx/64 Scope:Link
      UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
      RX packets:273688 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:33946 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
      RX bytes:409128994 (390.1 MiB)  TX bytes:4016030 (3.8 MiB)
      Interrupt:20 Memory:f7f00000-f7f20000

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback
      inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
      inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
      UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
      RX packets:313 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:313 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:0
      RX bytes:49781 (48.6 KiB)  TX bytes:49781 (48.6 KiB)

venet0    Link encap:UNSPEC  HWaddr 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00
      inet6 addr: fe80::1/128 Scope:Link
      UP BROADCAST POINTOPOINT RUNNING NOARP  MTU:1500  Metric:1
      RX packets:351 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:338 errors:0 dropped:5 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:0
      RX bytes:180727 (176.4 KiB)  TX bytes:109667 (107.0 KiB)

vmbr0     Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr xxx
      inet addr:xxx  Bcast:xxx  Mask:255.255.255.248
      inet6 addr: xxx/64 Scope:Link
      UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
      RX packets:35361 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:33722 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:0
      RX bytes:392904370 (374.7 MiB)  TX bytes:4002892 (3.8 MiB)
```

Without wondershaper:

```
wget -O /dev/null http://speedtest.dal01.softlayer.com/downloads/test100.zip
--2015-10-15 10:12:35--  http://speedtest.dal01.softlayer.com/downloads/test100.zip
Resolving speedtest.dal01.softlayer.com (speedtest.dal01.softlayer.com)... 74.86.116.210, 2607:f0d0:1003:31::2
Connecting to speedtest.dal01.softlayer.com (speedtest.dal01.softlayer.com)|74.86.116.210|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: 104874307 (100M) [application/zip]
Saving to: `/dev/null'

39% [============================================================================>                                                                                                                       ] 41,468,482  27.3M/s              ^C
```

I configure wondershaper:

```
# wondershaper vmbr0 1000000 1000000
```

Result...:

```
wget -O /dev/null http://speedtest.dal01.softlayer.com/downloads/test100.zip
--2015-10-15 10:12:56--  http://speedtest.dal01.softlayer.com/downloads/test100.zip
Resolving speedtest.dal01.softlayer.com (speedtest.dal01.softlayer.com)... 74.86.116.210, 2607:f0d0:1003:31::2
Connecting to speedtest.dal01.softlayer.com (speedtest.dal01.softlayer.com)|74.86.116.210|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: 104874307 (100M) [application/zip]
Saving to: `/dev/null'

 0% [                                                                                                                                                                                                    ] 61,970      18.4K/s  eta 87m 39s ^C
```

(Between 6ko/sec and 18ko/sec...)

Config on wondershaper after this test :

```
#wondershaper vmbr0
qdisc cbq 1: root refcnt 2 rate 10000Kbit (bounded,isolated) prio no-transmit
 Sent 546883 bytes 776 pkt (dropped 0, overlimits 0 requeues 0)
 rate 0bit 0pps backlog 0b 0p requeues 0
  borrowed 0 overactions 0 avgidle 12500 undertime 0
qdisc sfq 10: parent 1:10 limit 127p quantum 1514b divisor 1024 perturb 10sec
 Sent 15781 bytes 123 pkt (dropped 0, overlimits 0 requeues 0)
 rate 0bit 0pps backlog 0b 0p requeues 0
qdisc sfq 20: parent 1:20 limit 127p quantum 1514b divisor 1024 perturb 10sec
 Sent 530850 bytes 647 pkt (dropped 0, overlimits 0 requeues 0)
 rate 0bit 0pps backlog 0b 0p requeues 0
qdisc sfq 30: parent 1:30 limit 127p quantum 1514b divisor 1024 perturb 10sec
 Sent 0 bytes 0 pkt (dropped 0, overlimits 0 requeues 0)
 rate 0bit 0pps backlog 0b 0p requeues 0
qdisc ingress ffff: parent ffff:fff1 ----------------
 Sent 695844 bytes 1291 pkt (dropped 20, overlimits 0 requeues 0)
 rate 0bit 0pps backlog 0b 0p requeues 0
class cbq 1: root rate 10000Kbit (bounded,isolated) prio no-transmit
 Sent 252 bytes 6 pkt (dropped 0, overlimits 0 requeues 0)
 rate 0bit 0pps backlog 0b 0p requeues 0
  borrowed 0 overactions 0 avgidle 12500 undertime 0
class cbq 1:1 parent 1: rate 1000Mbit (bounded,isolated) prio 5
 Sent 547619 bytes 772 pkt (dropped 0, overlimits 0 requeues 0)
 rate 0bit 0pps backlog 0b 0p requeues 0
  borrowed 0 overactions 0 avgidle 12500 undertime 0
class cbq 1:10 parent 1:1 leaf 10: rate 1000Mbit prio 1
 Sent 16769 bytes 125 pkt (dropped 0, overlimits 0 requeues 0)
 rate 0bit 0pps backlog 0b 0p requeues 0
  borrowed 0 overactions 0 avgidle 12500 undertime 0
class cbq 1:20 parent 1:1 leaf 20: rate 900000Kbit prio 2
 Sent 530850 bytes 647 pkt (dropped 0, overlimits 0 requeues 0)
 rate 0bit 0pps backlog 0b 0p requeues 0
  borrowed 0 overactions 0 avgidle 12500 undertime 0
class cbq 1:30 parent 1:1 leaf 30: rate 800000Kbit prio 2
 Sent 0 bytes 0 pkt (dropped 0, overlimits 0 requeues 0)
 rate 0bit 0pps backlog 0b 0p requeues 0
  borrowed 0 overactions 0 avgidle 12500 undertime 0
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't found the way to fix this issue with wondershaper, but found an other way to do the same with ethtool :

```
ethtool -s eth0 speed 100 duplex full
```

Comment: Ahem. To clarify, this doesn't "do the same thing" although it does achieve what you want (limiting the speed to 100Mbps). It limits the NIC interface to 100Mbps (effectively disabling Gigabit) but isn't always an available option.